# Separate Gradle source set for integration tests using Kotlin DSL

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm working on a Spring Boot application implemented in [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), and would like to migrate the Gradle build to use the [Gradle Kotlin DSL](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl).

The one thing I cannot figure out is how to set up a [separate source set](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:separate_test_type_source_files) and task for my integration tests.

My source tree looks like this:

```
src
├── integrationTest
│   ├── kotlin
│   └── resources
├── main
│   ├── kotlin
│   └── resources
└── test
    ├── kotlin
    └── resources
```

And the source set and task are set up like this with Gradle's Groovy DSL:

```
// build.gradle
sourceSets {
    integrationTest {
        kotlin {
            compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output + configurations.testRuntimeClasspath
            runtimeClasspath += output + compileClasspath
        }
    }
}

configurations {
    integrationTestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
    integrationTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}

task integrationTest(type: Test, dependsOn: []) {
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
}
```

I've found many examples for using the Gradle Kotlin DSL, and for additional source sets - but nothing for the combination.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integration tests with Gradle Kotlin DSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52904603/integration-tests-with-gradle-kotlin-dsl)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you can translate the Groovy script to the Kotlin DSL:

```
java {
    sourceSets {
        val integrationTest by creating {
            kotlin.apply {
                compileClasspath += sourceSets["main"].output + configurations.testRuntimeClasspath
                runtimeClasspath += output + compileClasspath
            }
        }
    }
}

configurations["integrationTestCompile"].extendsFrom(configurations["testCompile"])
configurations["integrationTestRuntime"].extendsFrom(configurations["testRuntime"])

val integrationTest by tasks.creating(Test::class) {
    val integrationTestSourceSet = java.sourceSets["integrationTest"]
    testClassesDirs = integrationTestSourceSet.output.classesDirs
    classpath = integrationTestSourceSet.runtimeClasspath
}
```

Also see: the [Migrating build logic from Groovy to Kotlin](https://guides.gradle.org/migrating-build-logic-from-groovy-to-kotlin/) guide by Gradle